# C++: assigning a std::string to a buffer array

Tags: c++, string, c++17

I have been facing this a lot when dealing with code that have to interop with C code, where you have a `std::string` where you need to copy its contents to a plain char buffer, like this:

```
struct T
{
    int i;
    char cstr[size + 1];
};

// `std::` removed here for clarity only.
void f(vector<pair<int, string>> const& in)
{
   T* out = new/malloc whatever.

   for (size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i) {
       out[i].i = in[i].first;
       strncpy(out[i].cstr, in[i].c_str(), sizeof(out[i].cstr));
   }

   // whatever
}
```

However, that's unconvinient and not too expressive. I would prefer instead to do something more similar to:

```
void f(vector<pair<int, string>> const& in)
{
   T* out = new/malloc whatever.

   for (size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i)
       out[i] = T{ in[i].first, in[i].c_str() };

   // whatever
}
```

How to solve this "string-copy-problem"? The only solution is by an object that is able to wrap the c-array so that the operator= "does the right thing", to enable a pattern like:

```
void f(vector<pair<int, string>> const& in)
{
   T* out = new/malloc whatever.

   for (size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i)
       std::tie(out[i].id, WRAPPER(out[i].cstr)) = in[i];

   // whatever
}
```

Is there anything in the language or the standard library that have already solved "that problem?" Or my only choice is to build my own class with the proper semantics? (I know how to do it by myself; I'm asking if there's something made already).

Comment: **Never** remove included headers and `std::` when posting a [mcve]. I would like to show you a solution, copied your code and stopped at reluctance of getting the code compiled.

Comment: What is the primary goal here? Serialize a `vector` of `string` into a `char` array? I don't know of any built-in trick to do this. `<algorithm>` has helper functions to automate parts of the job, but you'll have to stitch them together.

Comment: That structure with the size followed by the string is quite unusual, do you really have a need for exactly that?

Comment: If the answer is, "I'm going to send it out a serial port or network socket[,]" remember that `int` does not a have a size or endian guaranteed by the Standard. To be 100% safe, you'll still have to do serialization.

Comment: I don't think there is anything in standard library to do that. And I don't think it's possible if `T` is supposed to be compatible with C (except from just just wrapping it in a factory function).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you can always make `T` the parent of a more capable class that adds any capabilities you need.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to inherit the C `struct` and add a converting constructor.

Example:

```cpp
struct T {
    int i;
    char cstr[size + 1];
};

struct T2 : T { // Note: No new member variables added!
    T2(const std::pair<int, std::string>& pair) : T{pair.first} {
        std::strncpy(cstr, pair.second.c_str(), sizeof cstr);
        cstr[sizeof cstr - 1] = '\0';        
    }
};
```

With that, you can get more expressivenesss in your C++ code:

```cpp
void f(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> const& in) {
    std::vector<T2> out(in.begin(), in.end());

    //...
}
```

You can then slice `T2` into `T` and provide a pointer to each element if you want:

```cpp
for (T& t : out) { // slice
    std::cout << t.i << ' ' << t.cstr << " ptr: " << &t << '\n';
}
```

Or call a C function with `out.data(), out.size()` looking something like this:

```
// a C function
void foo(T* ts, size_t size) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%d %s %p\n", ts[i].i, ts[i].cstr, (void*)&ts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the context of the OP's code, using this `T2` type could look like this: `T* out = new/malloc whatever; for (size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i) { out[i] = T2{in[i]}; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that's true. I went for a vector to make it as idiomatic as I could think of, but yes, you are correct.